# One Xeon E5-2620 or two Xeon E5-2407 for simple virtualization tasks?

Tags: cpu, virtualization

i'm configuring our first real server on Dell website and i don't know if i should choose one processor (2620) or two (2407). The server will run XenServer with 5 o 6 VMs (Debian and Windows) with pretty basic tasks (SVN, file sharing, simple web hosting). The idea is to buy one 2620 in the first place and than add a second one once we need more computational power. Is it a good idea? Will 16GB of memory be enough? The RAID controller i've choose is H730 with 1GB cache, is it the right choice for this task or i may encounter some bottleneck problems?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is it depends. All I can give you is advice in how to approach this problem.

RAM

It's usually a good idea to not over-allocate RAM. The best RAM amount you can add to your server should be the sum of the RAM your machines will use + 1 or 2 GB for the hypervisor. This way you make sure that your VM's will not be starved for memory in case one goes haywire and takes up all of its allocated space.

CPU

Depending on the load of your VM's you can over-allocate CPU. That being said the E5-2620v3 has 12 threads(6 cores + Hyperthreading) versus 2x E5-2407v2 which only have 8 threads combined (2x 4 cores). Personally I would go for the 2620 because it has more threads, but also because when running a two CPU server you have to take into account [NUMA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-uniform_memory_access).